# On my website, how can I get user designed product(in Silverlight) and view it later?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I'm creating a small website in MVC3, as a small project for college. Now, what I want is my website to provide the user an environment where they can design a rough estimate of their clothes, like T-shirts,etc. and then can order them.

An admin is supposed to view their order, prepare closest possible match and deliver it to them.

I have designed the website for showing ready made products, but how do I get through this designing environment part?  I mean not a very fancy environment is required, just good enough to be shown to the college management.

What technology/platform should I use? I don't know if flash can be used and all that but I want a simple and quick solution.  Although I would like to hear someone telling the areas of silverlight I need to study for it, because I have worked with it earlier a very little bit.

And actually I don't have an idea of how to save user's product for viewing later?  That is a the biggest problem I think.

UPDATE: I meant just a demo app, for example you can select the base color for a few items-shirt/t-shirt, then add some strips or design on it, then select a few elements from tools provided on one side-buttons/some style elements, thats all. I just want to give an impression that website can be put to use if the app is well worked with by some else,probably some other time. I mean the idea is to proove that its feasible via Silverlight/whatever technology I use for this to take orders from users which they have designed themselves.

Comment: Could you provide a detailed description of what exactly you intend to allow them to "design"?  Be specific.  There are companies that have spent tens of thousands of man hours building what you described.  Here's an example of a site that does this: http://www.zazzle.com/cr/design/pt-zazzle_shirt  Are you trying to go that far?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad... do you have a sample code that you have started or example. The best i can give you is that every component is that they will have coordinates and so on to be used and saved later.

You could download this sample project to help you get going:

http://codeding.com/articles/freehand-drawing-in-silverlight

The more specific question will be much easier to answer.